# Output play lists in Videos by Dukt

Tags: plugin-duktvideos

Is it possible to output whole playlists in the videos plugin by Dukt?
I have looked through the docs, but cannot see any examples or mention of this. But in the back-end system there are playlists.

Answer (score 2):

The plugin is only showing the playlists in the CP, in the Videos explorer, to help you pick a video to be used in a video field. It is not currently possible to list playlists and their videos from the templates, but it’s on our list of things to explore for Videos 2.0.